# How to get base ref branch in a GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to know against which base a branch has a pull request open (if any). For example I have a `dev` branch and I want to perform a certain job **ONLY** if it has a PR open against `master`.

In the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts), it says we can see the base ref with `github.base_ref`. But it also says:

> This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either pull_request or pull_request_target.

Is there a way to know the base ref on every push to `dev`?

This is my code, but this only works once when I create the PR (and not on every push):

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.base_ref == 'refs/heads/dev' }}
    ...
```

Comment: A `push` event is triggered on any push, which means there might not be a PR against any branch. Furthermore, the `push` event doesn't know if there is a PR. This is what the `pull_request` event is for. Also note that the `pull_request` event has an attribute `branches`, which allows you to specify when it should trigger.

Comment: My understanding is that the `pull_request` is triggered only when a PR is created, not on **every** commit to its branch, correct?

Comment: No, `pull_request` is triggered on [all sorts of activity around PRs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request).